# How to use Jasmine with a page that expects localStorage to be set?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, local-storage

I have a page that reads from localStorage when the document is ready.

But the Jasmine beforeEach hook seems to run after the document is ready.

So, how to prepare the localStorage using Jasmine before the document is ready or before the page loads?

Comment: Maybe the design of page is poor. If the reading of localStorage were called at a different time, then it might be easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

A more jasmine-approved way would be to add a [custom jasmine reporter](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/custom_reporter.html).

You can do something like this:

```
var myReporter = {
  jasmineStarted: function(suiteInfo) {
    localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
  }
};
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(myReporter);
```

You just need to make sure that your reporter is registered early enough.

Comment: This seems better. Is there a way to use `jasmineStarted` or similar without a "Reporter"?

Comment: I don't think this would work in this case anyway because I need the function to run before the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

One way that works is to set `localStorage` at the top of the spec file, before the first `describe`.

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar);    

describe( 'Updates localStorage', function(){
  ...
```